# Search server for empty folders

Tags: bash, terminal, directory

My company uses a deeply nested folder structure for every project. I want to run a script on the server that runs through every folder, checks if empty, and returns a total number of instances that were empty.

So for example, of the 500 project folders, only 3% had any data in the Scans folder. This way we can identify which folders can be dropped using data - and not anecdotes.

I do not mind using excel to get the data formatted as I need but a list of empty folder name totals would be great.

Scans 500 folders, 12 empty
Script Notes 500 folders, 129 empty

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

find already comes equipped to handle this:

```
find . -type d -empty
```

or to execute some command on finding the empty dir:

```
find . -type d -empty -exec rmdir {} \;
```

and to get the count of empty dirs:

```
find . -type d -empty | wc -l
```

Example:

```
[12:30:21] wthom@dragon21:~/test [9] mkdir test2
[12:30:23] wthom@dragon21:~/test [10] mkdir test3
[12:30:26] wthoma2@dragon21:~/test [11] find . -type d -empty | wc -l
2
[12:30:29] wthoma2@dragon21:~/test [12] find . -type d -empty
./test2
./test3
```